# Apache2 two virtualhosts with ssl

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I have strange error message when I configure this in my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.test.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.test.com

    ... # all the stuff for my django app that most certainly does not relate to the issue at hand

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/www.test.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/www.test.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/www.test.com.ca
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache2 wont restart, due to configuration issue:

```
[Fri Jul 08 11:36:24.388010 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 23159] AH02240: Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)
[Fri Jul 08 11:36:24.388057 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 23159] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

Can anybody comment on this? I do not understand why this happens.

Comment: You have both Vhost configured to *:443, i suggest to change the one that redirects to *:80 ?

Comment: well, I want a redirect from https ://test.com to https ://www.test.com ; its a redirect from https to https

Comment: use this in .htaccess
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: I dont have a htaccess. Can I use it in virtualhost? If yes where? In a <directory>?

Comment: Yea <directory> should be fine